# Match Sku with Product ID and Is in Stock in Magento 1.9

Tags: mysql, magento-1.9

I am trying to get a table that displays:

**SKU**

**product_id**

**is_in_stock**

I got this which displays SKU and Product ID in a table and I want to add is_in_stock to it, I got this:

```
SELECT entity_id as product_id, sku FROM catalog_product_entity;
```

catalog_product_entity table:

[image]

I need to add is_in_stock column now from table `cataloginventory_stock_item`, this table holds the product ID column.

[image]

How can I do that?

This is my output, I need to add a column is_in_stock to it from different table but am struggling:

[image]

Comment: Please add the schema of the two tables. If possible sample and expected data.

Comment: entity_id and product_id are the same, but I need to add the column is_in_stock to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [MySQL Join Made Easy](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) to get the logic of the query below:

```
SELECT A.entity_id as product_id, A.sku, B.is_in_stock 
FROM catalog_product_entity A INNER JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item B
ON A.entity_id=B.product_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the query I was looking for. It was this if anyone even needs it:

```
SELECT p.entity_id as product_id, p.sku, c.is_in_stock 
FROM catalog_product_entity as p
INNER JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item as c 
ON p.entity_id = c.product_id
```